# Formal definition of a conjunction of $n$ propositional atoms

Tags: definition, propositional-calculus

Let $n$ be a positive integer, and consider a set $\{p_1,...,p_n\}$ of $n$ propositional atoms. I want to rigorously define the set of all conjunctions such that each atom appears once and only once. For example, letting $n$ be $3$, and letting $p_1 = p$, $p_2 = q$, $p_3 = r$, the set of conjunctions would include $12$ elements, such as $((p \land q) \land r)$, $((q \land p) \land r)$, $(p \land (q \land r))$, etc. Of course, the conjunctions are all equivalent, but I still want to define formally the set of all such conjunctions.

Answer (score 1):

This should already be more-or-less taken care of by how you formally make sense of sentences in the first place. For example, if we read "sentence" as "function from some $n\in\omega$ to $\{p_1,...,p_n\}\cup\{(,),\wedge,\vee,\neg\}$ satisfying [properties]," then you're just looking at $$\{\sigma\in\mathsf{Sent}: \forall i\in\{1,...,n\}[\vert\sigma^{-1}(p_i)\vert=1]\}.$$ Different formalizations of sentences will result in different details, but the general picture should be the same according to any reasonable approach I can think of.